# Organizar coluna Período no SQL em forma crescente ou decrescente

Tags: sql, query

Pessoal estou com uma seguinte dúvida/problema

Estou fazendo um select em algumas contas e organizava pelo nome do arquivo, porém eu preciso organizar pelo período porém não estou conseguindo pelo fato de não ser uma unica data. Não posso utilizar a data da criação delas.

Meu select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Periodo, Nome_Arquivo, Tel FROM Arquivos WHERE Id_Cliente = 999 ORDER BY Periodo
```

e o que me resulta é isso:

```
23/01/2016 até 22/02/2016   teste73xczx.txt 11 9999-9999
23/01/2017 até 22/02/2017   teste1773zx.txt 11 9999-9999
23/02/2016 até 22/03/2016   testezxczxc.txt 11 9999-9999
23/03/2016 até 22/04/2016   testezxczx.txt  11 9999-9999
```

gostaria de deixar crescente porém mesmo colocando, então ficaria assim

```
23/01/2016 até 22/02/2016   teste73xczx.txt 11 9999-9999
23/02/2016 até 22/03/2016   testezxczxc.txt 11 9999-9999
23/03/2016 até 22/04/2016   testezxczx.txt  11 9999-9999
23/01/2017 até 22/02/2017   teste1773zx.txt 11 9999-9999
```

alguém teria alguma ideia?

Talvez com mais exemplo, o resultado total do id:
Periodos:

```
23/01/2016 até 22/02/2016
23/01/2017 até 22/02/2017
23/02/2016 até 22/03/2016
23/03/2016 até 22/04/2016
23/04/2016 até 22/05/2016
23/05/2016 até 22/06/2016
23/06/2016 até 22/07/2016
23/07/2016 até 22/08/2016
23/08/2016 até 22/09/2016
23/09/2016 até 22/10/2016
23/10/2016 até 22/11/2016
23/11/2016 até 22/12/2016
23/12/2016 até 22/01/2017
```

Comment: Ideia: Cria uma coluna data_inicial e outra data_final sendo ambas timestamp e faz um script pra varrer todas as linhas dessa tabela e preencher essas duas colunas no formato yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00 com os valores pegos da string da coluna Periodo(pode usar uns explodes aí pra pegar os pedaços). Após ter normalizado essa tabela vai poder fazer ordenação por data.

Comment: Tá querendo ordenar pela quantidade de dias entre as datas crescente?

Comment: @MurilloGoulart Quero organizar da maneira que ficou o segundo resultado

Comment: Qual o critério pra dizer que um período vem antes do outro?

Comment: Perguntei pq mesmo vendo tá difícil de entender a lógica.

Comment: existem varios arquivos de cobrança, e cada arquivo tem um periodo eu só estou demonstrando  o resultado de 4, mas existem diversos registros com os periodos informados então ele me retorna tudo resumidamente pelo distinct porém o periodo não esta ordenado preciso que a data final seja ordenado 09/2015 10/2015 01/2016 02/2016, porém o ano está errado no exemplo que demonstrei

Comment: Coloquei o exemplo ao todo de como está ficando

Answer (score 0):

Eu separei a data do periodo pelo mês e pelo ano assim consegui uma construção organizada da tabela

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Periodo, Nome_Arquivo,
    LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Periodo,19,2)) as MesFinal,
    LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Periodo,22,4)) as AnoFinal,
    Tel FROM Vox_Arquivos WHERE Id_Cob_Clientes = 9999 order by AnoFinal desc,MesFinal desc
```

resultado

```
23/01/2017 até 22/02/2017
23/12/2016 até 22/01/2017
23/11/2016 até 22/12/2016
23/10/2016 até 22/11/2016
23/09/2016 até 22/10/2016
23/08/2016 até 22/09/2016
23/07/2016 até 22/08/2016
```

A parte da ideia de separação surgiu com base no comentário do Antonio Alexandre(Primeiro comentário da pergunta), muito obrigado!